# Try to understanding Delphi Interfaces

Tags: delphi, interface

I'm reading the Nick Hodges' book "Coding in Delphi" to learn the Delphi Programming Language and I'm trying to understand the interface usage part in the book.

In a unit, I've put a simple interface:

```
unit INameInterface;

interface

type
  IName = interface
  ['{CE5E1B61-6F44-472B-AE9E-54FF1CAE0D70}']
    function FirstName: string;
    function LastName: string;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

and in another unit, I've put the implementation of this interface, according to the book sample:

```
unit INameImplementation;

interface

uses
  INameInterface;

type
  TPerson = class(TInterfacedObject, IName)
    protected
      function FirstName: string;
      function LastName: string;
  end;

implementation

{ TPerson }

function TPerson.FirstName: string;
begin
  Result := 'Fred';
end;

function TPerson.LastName: string;
begin
  Result := 'Flinstone';
end;

end.
```

At this point, I've created a simple VCL form application in order to use the object I've created. The form code is this:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, INameImplementation;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    lblFirtName: TLabel;
    lblLastName: TLabel;
    txtFirstName: TStaticText;
    txtLastName: TStaticText;
    btnGetName: TButton;
    procedure btnGetNameClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Person: TPerson;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  txtFirstName.Caption := '';
  txtLastName.Caption := '';
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnGetNameClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  txtFirstName.Caption := ...
end;

end.
```

My question is this: how can I use the interface? The two functions are declared as protected so how can I access them from the form? Do I have to define them as public, or should I use the `INameInterface` interface unit?

I'm terribly confused about interfaces!!!

Comment: One great example of how interfaces are used... Suppose you have a DLL with an object inside of it which you'd like to use from within the calling process as well. You cannot pass objects across the DLL boundaries, but you can pass interfaces (so long as the members of it are also safe, such as WideString instead of String). Then, you instantiate the object inside of the DLL, and pass an interface reference of that object from the DLL back to the calling app - then the calling app can interact with that interface the same way as if you're calling the object directly.

Comment: @Jerry That's more of an implementation issue with binary interop. I think interfaces are a deeper concept.

Answer (score 9):

Essentially there are three things for you to know, beyond what you have already demonstrated understanding.

**1. How to call methods of an interface**

If you have a reference to an interface, then you can call methods just as you would on a class reference:

```
var
  Name: IName;
....
Writeln(Name.FirstName);
Writeln(Name.LastName);
```

**2. How to obtain interface references**

Typically you do this by instantiating a class that implements the interface you wish to use:

```
var
  Name: IName;
....
Name := TPerson.Create;
// now you can use Name as before
```

There are other ways to obtain interface references, but let's leave those to one side for now.

**3. How to pass around interfaces**

You might not wish to create a new object every time you need to use an interface. So you can get other parties to pass you the interface to use. For instance interfaces can be passed as method parameters:

```
procedure Foo(Name: IName);
begin
  // use Name as before
end;
```

You can obtain interface references via function calls and properties, etc.

---

> The two functions are declared as `protected` so how can I access them from the form?

Well, they are declared `protected` in the implementing object. But you are not going to access them via the implementing object. You will access them via the interface. Which means that the visibility in the implementing object is not relevant from the perspective of the interface.

Your form unit references `INameImplementation` which is needed to create the object that implements the interface. You'll also need to use `INameInterface` so that your code can see the interface itself.

This example isn't very powerful yet because you can still see the implementing object's type. But imagine if that was hidden from you and all you could see was a function that returned an `IName`. It's when you reach this point that interfaces can achieve their potential.

Comment: Than's very much David. 
Just another question: so I've to include INameInterface and  INameImplementation in the uses clause of the main unit. Is this the normal usage of this kind of objects?

Comment: There's a lot more to be said on interfaces than this but I tried to stick to the basics. I trust nick's book says plenty more.

Comment: @Eros: all interface consumers should only reference the interface unit. Dependency injection is a natural fit for this style of coding.

Comment: I think our OP is not ready for that level of mental gymnastics.